# WSO2: How to generate access_token with scopes using access_token or id_token generated with scope:openid from Identity server login

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

we are using WSO2 API Manager-3.2.0 & IdentityServer-5.10.0.

We are developing an web application (angular) with SSO using Identity server-5.10.0 OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration.

I've successfully implemented the login, the redirects/callbacks are working and I am getting the access_tokens and id_tokens.

I am trying to generate access_token with scopes using the access_token/id_token generated in previous step, but it is generating default access_token even though user has access to  scopes specified in the request.

Using below API used for generating access_token:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://AM_HOST:9443/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic base64(clientId:clientSecret)' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' \
--data-urlencode 'assertion=access_token/id_toekn' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=scopes'
```

But how to generate access_token with scopes associated with user role?

Comment: 1. Identity Server doesn't return partial set of scopes if the user doesn't have access to all requested scopes.
2. Have you defined `role -> scopes` mappings in the IS?
3. Does your ID token contains role claim? (Because the JWT grant considers the subject user as federated user. Therefore, will not be checking local user account.)

Comment: @ Nipun Thathsara , thankyou for your response, How to get the scopelist based on user role, so that we can pass only scopes associated with user to the Token API request or is there a way to get the partial scopes in the token response if user doesn't have access to all requested scopes